# R: rCharts rPlot does not display

Tags: r, rcharts

I have the following dataframe below:

```
   QUINT1 QUINT2 n
    1       1     0.19
    1       2     0.01
    2       1     0.01
    2       2     0.17
    2       3     0.02
    2       4     0.001
    3       2     0.02
    3       3     0.16
    3       4     0.02
    4       3     0.02
    4       4     0.17
    4       5     0.01
    5       4     0.01
    5       5     0.19
```

I am trying to make an interactive heat map using the code below:

```
p5 = rPlot(x = 'QUINT1', y = 'QUINT2', color = 'n', data = graphdata, type = 'tile')
p5$save("heatmap.html",standalone=TRUE)
```

However, NOTHING displays when I open the HTML graph. I get the console error `uncaught exception: DefinitionError: Bad specification.` I have tried to open this in Firefox, Chrome, and Internet Explorer with no luck. The plot also does not display in the RStudio Viewer.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `p5 = rPlot(x = 'bin(QUINT1,1)', y = 'bin(QUINT2,1)', color = 'n', data = graphdata, type = 'tile')`

Comment: perfect! that solved my issue. thanks!